# Reorder factor levels by median of continuous variable in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, forcats

**Problem:**

I have a dataframe of two variables (age and group) and I want to build a boxplot of age by group. I want to order the group levels accordingly to their median age. For doing so, I tried to follow two tutorials ([here](https://forcats.tidyverse.org/reference/fct_reorder.html) and [here](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/267-reorder-a-variable-in-ggplot2.html)). I cannot figure out what am I doing wrong. Below, I provide a reproducible example.

**Reproducible example:**

My data:

```
df <- structure(list(age = c(27, 28, 22, 28, 35, 25, 23, 28, 29, 26, 51, 29, 30, 29, 22, 23, 22, 22, 29, 27, 22, 43, 22, 36, 28, 24, 22, 22, 43, 22, 26, 24, 22, 24, 27, 23, 27, 22, 28, 32, 30, 22, 21, 30, 37, 28, 30, 31, 28, 24, 21, 30, 27, 33, 22, 29, 45, 30, 30, 23, 30, 23, 22, 30, 23, 28, 22, 28, 22, 22, 22,
 22, 19, 35, 24, 27, 23, 26, 22, 21, 26, 28, 29, 26, 42, 27, 28, 22, 22, 21, 41, 23, 31, 21, 30, 28, 28, 21, 21, 28, 24, 28, 29, 21, 27, 24, 28, 22, 23, 28, 22, 22, 28, 35, 29, 23, 23, 30, 28, 22, 29, 42, 
34, 29, 39, 35, 30, 32, 29, 27, 33, 30, 28, 22, 21, 28, 29, 28, 28, 29, 29, 29, 28, 29, 27, 28, 28, 28, 38, 29, 28, 28, 29, 22, 25, 30, 31, 30, 30, 30, 28, 29, 29, 26, 29, 29, 30, 28, 28, 22, 
29, 30, 28, 22, 22, 28, 22, 28, 29, 27, 29, 29, 29, 30, 30, 30, 51, 36, 28, 22, 38, 22, 21, 30, 28, 29, 28, 27, 24, 23), group = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 
3L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 1L,
 7L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 4L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("HN2", "HB2", "MN1", "HN1", "HB1", "MB1", "MB2", "MN2"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -200L), groups = structure(list(.rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 
    40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L,
101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 140L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 151L,
 152L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 156L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 161L, 162L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 166L, 167L, 168L, 169L, 170L, 171L, 172L, 173L, 174L, 175L, 176L, 177L, 178L, 179L, 180L, 181L, 182L, 183L, 184L, 185L, 186L, 187L, 188L, 189L, 190L, 191L, 192L, 193L, 194L, 195L, 196L, 197L, 198L, 199L, 200L), 
ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -200L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), class = c("rowwise_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The boxplot without reordering factor levels:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

p1 <- df %>% ggplot(aes(x = group, y=age, fill = group)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none"
  )
```

**What I tried:**

Following the first tutorial to reorder factor levels:

```
library(forcats)

p2 <- df %>% mutate(group = fct_reorder(group, age, median)) %>%
 ggplot(aes(x = group, y=age, fill = group)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none"
  )
```

Following the second tutorial to reorder factor levels:

```
p3 <- df %>% mutate(group = fct_reorder(group, age, .fun="median")) %>%
 ggplot(aes(x = group, y=age, fill = group)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none"
  )
```

All three produced the same results with groups not ordered by their median age:

```
ggarrange(p1, p2, p3)
```

[image: boxplots]

Why is it not working?

**What I expect:** something like the [first tutorial solution](https://forcats.tidyverse.org/reference/fct_reorder.html), but for my own data and with ggplot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is grouped rowwise. You need to `ungroup` it before applying `fct_reorder` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)

df %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(group = fct_reorder(group, age, median)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = group, y=age, fill = group)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none"
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! (+) How did you discovered the problem? I had this problem before with other datasets...  Maybe it is something I am doing wrong constantly

Comment: When you print your data in the console with `df`, it shows that the data is grouped.  When you use `mutate` under grouped data it is applied only to the values in that group and not the entire dataset. As your data is grouped rowwise `fct_reorder` is first applied to only 1st row, then 2nd row etc. In general, it is always a good practice that whenever you group a data (using `rowwise` or `group_by`) you should always ungroup it after all your operations on that data are done to avoid such unexpected consequences.

Answer (score 2):

You can reorder the x axis directly

```
df %>% ggplot(aes(x = fct_reorder(group, age, median), y=age, fill = group)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none"
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! (+1) Do you know why it works this way but not the way I was trying? I guess Ronak Shah got it in the other answer, but still, dont know why doing the way you suggested avoid the need to ungroup!